# OpenShift, Apache Tomcat and Struts2

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, openshift

everybody.
I have a big problem here, I have been looking for the solution but I don't find any post with the same problem, sorry for that.

Well, I developed a server with struts2, apache tomcat 7 and mysql. It works fine in local.

Now I want to upload to the cloud, I take the choice of OpenShift.
So I created an account and a new project with Tomcat 7 and mysql 5.5
I configured my eclipse framework with the plugin and also my git.

After that, I created an OpenShift project using my local project.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pfcserver</groupId>
<artifactId>pfcserver</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>pfcserver</name>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>           
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>pfcserver</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>        
                    <version>2.1.1</version>  
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>        
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And this my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>PFCServer</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>TitlePage.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Listener</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pfc.game.comunication.Listener</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Listener</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Listener</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My problem is that I run the application on OpenShift and appear the default page instead my Title.jsp.

pd: I can't upload a image with the structure of my project, my web.xml is in WEB-INF folder, my struts.xml is in src folder and my pom.xml is in the main project folder.

Thanks for any help and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you modified the pom.xml pretty heavily, and that openshift doesn't know how to deploy your application correctly, try setting the openshift section back to it's defaults and I think that will help (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/template/pom.xml)

Especially removing this part probably made it not work

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<configuration>
<outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
<warName>ROOT</warName>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I modified the pom.xml and got this error. I can't post all trace because I don't have enough points >.<  ERROR: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project pfcserver: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]

Comment: try merging ours with yours, you need that part of ours

Comment: I did it, the only diference between your pom.xml and my pom.xml is the app name and de struts dependency <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
  </dependency>